# Rounding an NSVisualEffectView's corners when inside another view

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm developing a MacOS application which uses an `NSVisualEffectView` (named "Rounded View" here) embedded within an application, as seen here:

[image: Storyboard Hierarchy]

[image: The App]

It is meant to provide a backdrop to an Image View. This works, but despite attempting every method I could possibly find, I cannot get this view's corners to become rounded.

### What I've Tried

(Note that I've tried every combination of these things together, too.)

#### Setting the Mask Image

I created a transparent, high-res PNG with a black rounded square and added it as an asset, setting it in the VisualEffectView's Mask Image property:

[image: Mask Image set in View]

This has absolutely no effect on anything.

#### Setting wantsLayer and cornerRadius

```
@IBOutlet weak var roundedView: NSVisualEffectView!

...

override func viewWillAppear() {
    view.window?.isOpaque = false
    roundedView.wantsLayer = true
    roundedView.layer!.cornerRadius = 20.0
}
```

This has no effect either.

#### Various Compositing Filters

I figured maybe setting a special blend mode would help. None of them force my intended tweaks to opacity to take effect.

Comment: try adding `roundedView.layer!.masksToBounds = true` to your viewWillAppear func.

Comment: @inexcitus It made no difference, unfortunately. I've noticed that there's also a `maskedCorners` property, though.. but it doesn't seem to do anything either if I set it to all four corners